# Laravel Dusk receives 403 error while Artisan serve does not.

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, http-status-code-403, laravel-dusk

I can run and use my site locally using `php artisan serve`. I created a basic Dusk test:

```
...
   $browser->visit('/')  
 ->assertSee('Lorem');  
...
```

when I run this test, it fails. Here is the generated screenshot:

[image: 403 error page]

My environment is OSX, Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Have you set the proper `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: I updated it to include the port number. This seems to have broken dusk

Comment: @Camilo put that in an answer and I will accept it. It did solve the error I had

Comment: Added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the proper `APP_URL` in your `.env` file.

Depending on your configuration, this could just be `http://localhost` or some custom domain name and even a port numer `http://myapp.test:8000`.

Dusk access the website using a browser, so without the proper URL all your tests are going to fail.